# x86 32-bit Support for Cuda

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am working on a vision system and using Opencv for image processing and I have to present the whole system as a 32 bit ActiveX control to be integrated in an IWS (Indosoft Web Studio) application as IWS is 32 bit.

How can I do that as I would need a 32 bit Opencv build with cuda support and there is no 32 bit Cuda toolkit any more. 
Can anyone please clarify the following from [Nvidia](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html).

> Native development using the CUDA Toolkit on x86_32 is unsupported.
>   Deployment and execution of CUDA applications on x86_32 is still
>   supported, but is limited to use with GeForce GPUs. To create 32-bit
>   CUDA applications, use the cross-development capabilities of the CUDA
>   Toolkit on x86_64.
>
> Support for developing and running x86 32-bit applications on x86_64
>   Windows is limited to use with: GeForce GPUs CUDA Driver CUDA Runtime
>   (cudart) CUDA Math Library (math.h) CUDA C++ Compiler (nvcc) CUDA
>   Development Tools

I can see the point but I can't find any direction on how to use the cross-development capabilities of the CUDA Toolkit on x86_64.

Comment: In other words, how can I build a 32 bit OpenCV with cuda support.

Comment: It means you open a project in visual studio on a 64-bit OS, and select win32 instead of x64 as your platform. However, there is no library support other than the CUDA runtime library and the CUDA driver API library. This means that CUFFT, CUBLAS, NPP, and other such libraries are only provided for use when the x64 platform is selected. If OpenCV had any dependency on NPP, for example, you would be out of luck. And I won't be able to write up a tutorial on how to build 32bit OpenCV with cuda support. Your best bet might be to revert to an older CUDA toolkit and environment, with 32-bit support

Comment: So i can't use cross-development capabilities or even if somehow i do, it is just limited to Geforce GPUs and 32 bit is deprecated after cuda toolkit 6.5.

Comment: Lets see if going back to cuda 6.5 is of any help.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I found [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cuda/cuda_installation.htm) and its says "set -m32 to your nvcc options". I don't know where could I set that option. may be in nvcc.profile but i don't know how.

Comment: that should be set automatically when you select a win32 project instead of x64.  You can confirm by inspecting the `nvcc` compile command lines that visual studio puts in the console window during compilation.

Answer (score 3):

Echoing a comment into an answer -- yes you can cross compile to 32 bit output using a 64 bit CUDA tool chain in Windows. However, NVIDIA ceased delivering 32 bit CUDA application libraries many years ago. Quoting Robert Crovella:

> This means that CUFFT, CUBLAS, NPP, and other such libraries are only
>   provided for use when the x64 platform is selected. If OpenCV had any
>   dependency on NPP, for example, you would be out of luck

Given OpenCV has dependencies on CUFFT, CUBLAS, and NPP, it is extremely unlikely that you can build and run a 32 bit OpenCV version using a modern CUDA toolkit because of the lack of libraries.

Comment: Does this mean OpenCV can't be compiled 32 bit for Cuda ? For example, I want to run my mask rcnn model with 32 bit with Opencv + cuda.

Comment: @FishCoder: A standard OpenCV tree cannot be successfully compiled with CUDA installed for a 32 bit target.